# Java Android, HttpURLConnection blocks when trying connect to a host which not exist

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am writing a application on android, which will download a picture from the internet.
While I test the download module, I found this strange thing, when I let the HttpURLConnection to try to connect to a host which does not exist, it just blocks there despite I have set the timeout parameter.

The code is here:

```
            String[] ext = link.split("\\.");
            String extension = ext[ext.length-1];
            String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+appInfo.getState(AppInfo.STORE_IMAGE)+File.separator;
            String fileName = id+"."+extension;
            File file = new File(filePath+fileName);

            URL url = new URL(link);
            URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
            url = uri.toURL();
            link = url.toString();

            Log.i("link", link);

            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;

            try {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
                connection.connect();
            } catch (java.net.SocketTimeoutException e) {
                throw new Exception("timeout");
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                throw new Exception("timeout");
            }

            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                        + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            input = connection.getInputStream();
            output = new FileOutputStream(filePath+fileName);

            byte data[] = new byte[4096];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
```

It won't return or throw an exception.

In the DBMS, I can see an error few minute later after it blocks.
And when I make it connect to an exist host, it returns an error quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't block. It throws a NullPointerException when you try to set the connect timeout on the null connection.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've edit the code above, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: You need to fix your exception handling. You are suppressing the actual exception and logging one of your own devising. You need to log the actual exception you are getting. It will tell all.